# How to build start token for list getchanges?

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, modern-experience, pnp, pnpjs

Using PnP JS for brevity.  I am having major difficulty figuring out what date time format the following requires.

Use case: I have date time for my last cache, I want to get the differences in my list since then. Any help great appreciated.

```
const SOMEDATE= I have no idea  

const changeTokenStart = `1;3;${resource};${SOMEDATE};-1`;


const changeQuery: IChangeQuery = {
    Add: true,
    Update: true,
    Item: true,
    ChangeTokenEnd: null,
    ChangeTokenStart: { StringValue: changeTokenStart },
};

const r = await list.getChanges(changeQuery);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use date time in below format:

```
const SOMEDATE = new Date("2022-02-22").getTime();

const changeTokenStart = `1;3;${resource};${SOMEDATE};-1`;
```

Basically, you have to pass the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970 00:00:00 - [getTime() function returns the same](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_gettime.asp)

**Documentation**: [Get changes on a list](https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/sp/lists/#get-changes-on-a-list)

Comment: Hi @Powell, did you try this? let me know if you need any further help with this.

Comment: Hi @Powell, Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it helped you in any way & it will help others with similar question in future to find the correct answer easily.

Answer (score 1):

According to my research and testing, please follow the following date time format:

```
const changeStart = new Date("2022-10-10").getTime();
```

Hope it can help you. Thanks for your understanding and support.

Comment: Which is exactly what I have explained in my answer below!